# What is a library stanza?

Tags: plutus, haskell, cabal

I deduce what stanza definitions are but I was struggling to find an exact definition and explanation why this is used in Haskell/Plutus.

- What exactly is a stanza?
- Can you compile code Haskell/Plutus code
  without using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you this article:

https://vrom911.github.io/blog/common-stanzas

Take into account that stanzas is a cabal thing (not Haskell, not Plutus). However Plutus projects can be created using cabal. Basically, it's the way a cabal file is organized: Libraries, executables, test-suites, etc.

Comment: If you answer someone's question, shouldn't you automatically vote for it?  It had 0 votes when I made this comment :-)

Comment: @gRebel, done. Thanks you for the reminder.